# Using the same key for different if statements in the keypressed function - processing

Tags: processing

I'm actually using Processing to check for entered values from the keyboard and take actions. Now the problem is that i would like to use the number "1" on the keyboard to take the two different action depending on an IF statement but the second condition doesn't seem to work. Pls, help me peruse this code as i don't know where i may be going wrong

```
void keyPressed() {

  if(page=="buttons")
{  
       if(key == '1') {
       text("This is the button page1", 30, 200);

                       }

       if(key == '2') {
       text("This is the button page2", 30, 200);

        }


else if(page=="options")
{  

      if (key == '1') {
      text("This is the options page", 100, 200);

  }
}
```

Comment: try adding `println(page)` in the beginning of `keyPressed` and see if it's ever `"options"`

Comment: I did but it did not work. That's why i'm wondering if an else if is not allowed in this kind of scenario. This is the first time i will be using it this way. I'm pretty new to processing.

Comment: found the problem. see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

There's a missing `}` before the `else if`. Also string comparison should be done with `.equals` instead of `==`. Here's the fixed one

```
void keyPressed() {

    if(page.equals("buttons")) {  
        if(key == '1') {
            text("This is the button page1", 30, 200);

        } else if(key == '2') {
            text("This is the button page2", 30, 200);

        }
    } else if(page.equals("options")) {  

        if (key == '1') {
            text("This is the options page", 100, 200);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. This is actually a dummy code which is identical to mine. I have edited the else if statement

Comment: Well the missing '}' still there, and is preventing the thing to work. Also never use `==` to compare [Strings](http://processing.org/reference/String.html), always prefer equals();